# GMod | Want to make a simple command that prints a colored message in the senders chatbox

Tags: lua, command, garrys-mod

I just want to make a simple script that prints a colored text in the chat of the sender after executing a specific command.

First the console gave me an error [attempt to index global 'chat' (a nil value)]. After reloading the Singleplayer and opening the script it didn't do anything.

Current Code:

```
local ply = LocalPlayer()

local function Test( ply, text, team )
    if string.sub( text, 1, 8 ) == "!command" then
        chat.AddText( Color( 100, 100, 255 ), "Test" )
    end
end
hook.Add( "PlayerSay", "Test", Test )
```

I hope that someone could help me.

Comment: Your code looks fine at first glance. Could you edit your question to include what exactly doesn't work? Are you getting any errors? Or does it simply do nothing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using LocalPlayer() (which is only called client-side) as well as chat.AddText() (again, only called client-side) inside of a "PlayerSay" hook (which is a server-side hook). You'd need something else, like [ChatPrint()](https://wiki.garrysmod.com/page/Player/ChatPrint)

EDIT: Just realized ChatPrint() doesn't accept Color() arguments in it... you could always try sending a net message:

```
if SERVER then 
    util.AddNetworkString( "SendColouredChat" )

    function SendColouredChat( ply, text )
        if string.sub( text, 1, 8 ) == "!command" then
            net.Start( "SendColouredChat" )
                net.WriteTable( Color( 255, 0, 0, 255 ) )
                net.WriteString( "Test" )
            net.Send( ply )
        end
    end
    hook.Add( "PlayerSay", "SendColouredChat", SendColouredChat )
end

if CLIENT then 
    function ReceiveColouredChat()
        local color = net.ReadTable()
        local str = net.ReadString()

        chat.AddText( color, str )
    end
    net.Receive( "SendColouredChat", ReceiveColouredChat )
end
```

EDIT: Returned to this question after a few years. For anyone else who may run into this later on, it's **much** simpler to just use the [GM:OnPlayerChat](https://wiki.facepunch.com/gmod/GM:OnPlayerChat) hook.

```
local function Command(ply, text, teamOnly, dead)
    if text:sub(1, 8) == "!command" then
        chat.AddText(Color(100, 100, 255), "Test")
    end
end
hook.Add("OnPlayerChat", "TestCommand", Command)
```

Comment: net.message would work for sure. I suggest not using "WriteTable" because it's way slower than sending a string or even, 1 string && 4 int's.